# Calculating Size of a Page Table

Tags: operating-system, virtual, page-tables

16-bit system, 32KiB physical memory. 1KiB page size. Each page table entry consists of the frame number, a Present/Absent bit, and a 2-bit long miscellaneous information field. Please calculate the size of the page table.

(32KiB/1KiB) * 2 bits=64 bits?

I thought it was just physical memory/page size times how long the miscellaneous field was but wouldn't that give us 64 bits? I don't think that's right but I may be mistaken, any and all help is much appreciated!!

Comment: The frame number is presumably 16-bits; then one bit for present/absent and two bits making 19-bits per page table entry. What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: The size of the page table CANNOT be calculated from the information provided. Unfortunately, there is a well-known and apparently widely-used textbook that gives idiotic questions like this.